# XCode Templates: moving AppDelegate

Tags: xcode, templates, appdelegate

I am currently working on some XCode templates to make my work easier. I copied the original templates and modified them to my needs. Until now, everything worked just fine. However, i can't find a way to move the generated AppDelegate files to a subfolder without ending up with two copies of them.

Does enybody know how to move the AppDelegate to a subfolder? Which template do i have to modify?

Thanks in advance!

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just managed to move all files as intended.

It is important to make sure you edit all files up the hierarchy to make sure every key in the `Definitions` section as well as every item in the `Nodes` section is changed to reflect the same folder structure.

UPDATE:
most templates contain a key-value pair like this:

```
<key>Ancestors</key>
<array>
    <string>com.apple.dt.unit.applicationBase</string>
    <string>com.apple.dt.unit.osxBase</string>
</array>`
```

In this case, you would have to edit the templates `applicationBase` and `osxBase` and, if aplicable, all the ancestors listed in these templates.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I'm basing my template on the SingleView template by apple, so I can't go into it's ancestors and change things.

Comment: @user2973562: sry for answering late. i edited my answer to address your question

Comment: As I said, my template inherits from some of apple's templates, so in order to change them I would have to actually copy all of them, change them, and use those copies as ancestors, so that I don't screw up Apple's default templates?

Comment: Exactly. You can find the default templates by right clicking the Xcode.app file in your programs folder and selecting 'show package contents'. The templates are stored in Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates

Comment: I'm able to change the group of Appdelegate. I want to change the physical path also. What I did is put a fuller structure in the template directory. And given the root folders name in the Nodes section. Now the folder structure is creating and corresponding group structure also creating. App delegate come under the group Classes/Appdelegate but it is created in the Xcode projects directory itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 14.3**

Here is an update for Xcode 14.3.  I will show how to put four of the standard swift files into a subfolder (Supporting Files), and change the order of files in Xcode's Project Navigator.

Here is the standard Xcode file organization and the one I'm creating.

[image: Xcode files in standard locations]
[image: Xcode files in Support Files folder]

To start with, here is the top-level hierarchy of the templates for the standard iOS App, showing how the templates are inherited and which templates handle which files.  The files are either built within the templates (B) or included whole in the folder with the template (I).  Some files are built across several templates.

[image: Template hierarchy]

Template A inherits Template B, by listing Template B as an Ancestor.  Notice, .cocoaTouchApplicationBase is listed as an ancestor in both .sceneLifecycleApplication and .application.SwiftUI.iOS.  The tree continues much deeper, but this level is enough to do what we want.

The five listed templates are all in this folder in the Xcode application package:

```
/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/iOS/Application
```

These files should not be changed in their original location.  Instead, they should be copied to your own Templates folder and modified there (see below).  The changes involve:

- Giving each template a unique Identifier.  In my case, I replaced `com.apple.dt.unit.xyz` in the original templates with `com.stern.xyz`.  You can use anything you want, as long as it's unique.
- Changing the template's Ancestors, to point to your modified
  templates
- Performing the changes to put files into the "Supporting Files"
  folder.  This involves adding "Supporting Files/" to the front of the
  file names in the Nodes and Definitions for the file, and adding a
  Group to the file's Definition with a value of "Supporting Files".
- Assigning a SortOrder, to specify the order they appear in Xcode's Project Navigator.  Lower numbered files appear above higher numbered files.

In each template folder, there is a file called TemplateInfo.plist.  The changes will be made to these files.  Double-click TemplateInfo.plist to open it in Xcode for editing.

**Steps**

Here are the steps to move AppDelegate, SceneDelegate, Assets, and LaunchScreen into a subfolder called "Supporting Files", and move Main.storyboard above ViewController and Info.plist in Xcode's Project Navigator.

1. Create a new folder called Templates in: `/Users/<username>/Library/Developer/Xcode`
2. Create a subfolder in Templates called `Application`, if you want your new template to appear in the existing Application section of the New Project window.  If you give it a different name, a new section will appear in the New Project window with that name.
3. Copy the five template folders into your Application folder

[image: Templates Folder]

4. Give App.xctemplate a new name.  I called it MyApp.xctemplate.  This name will appear in the New Project window.

[image: New Project Dialog]

5. Make changes to the five TemplateInfo.plist files as indicated by the red boxes.  Instead of `com.stern`, you can use your own reverse domain name.

**MyApp.xctemplate**

[image: MyApp.xctemplate]

**UIScene Lifecycle.xctemplate**

[image: UIScene Lifecycle.xctemplate 1/2]
[image: UIScene Lifecycle.xctemplate 2/2]

**Cocoa Touch App Base.xctemplate**

[image: Cocoa Touch App Base.xctemplate 1/2]
[image: Cocoa Touch App Base.xctemplate 2/2]

**Core Data Cocoa Touch App.xctemplate**

[image: Core Data Cocoa Touch App.xctemplate]

**IOS SwiftUI App.xctemplate**

[image: IOS SwiftUI App.xctemplate]

It may not seem necessary to include `iOS SwiftUI App.xctemplate`, since it does not handle any of the standard swift files.  It must be modified however, since it provides an alternate path to `com.apple.dt.unit.cocoaTouchApplicationBase`.  If Xcode finds the original version of the template, it will create a second AppDelegate.swift file in the top-level folder of the project.

**Final Thoughts**

I was able to change the position of Info.plist, by setting its SortOrder in MyApp.xctemplate, but this resulted in an incomplete Info.plist file being added to the project, so I removed the entry.

Even though it was written for Xcode 4, the document in this link is still very useful in understanding templates: [Xcode 4 Template Docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20180423060655/http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/xcode4-template-documentation).