# Move original AppDelegate to group in XCode Template

Tags: ios, xcode, templates, project, appdelegate

I am trying to create an Xcode template, based on the single view application template provided by Apple. I have a certain folder structure, and I want AppDelegate to be moved to one of the folders in the project. The problem is that I couldn't get it to work properly. When I try to do this (place AppDelegate.h in a folder called main that I have already created, but what happens is that it creates a new folder called main and places the .h file there.

Here is my attempt:
In the TemplateInfo.plist file for my template I have added this to the definitions part

```
<key>Definitions</key>
    <dict>
        <key>AppDelegate.h</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Group</key>
            <array>
                <string>main</string>
                <string>objc</string>
            </array>
            <key>Path</key>
            <string>AppDelegate.h</string>
            <key>TargetIndices</key>
            <array/>
        </dict>

        <key>main/</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Path</key>
            <string>main</string>
            <key>TargetIndices</key>
            <array/>
        </dict>

        <key>main/objc/</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Group</key>
            <string>main</string>
            <key>Path</key>
            <string>objc</string>
            <key>TargetIndices</key>
            <array/>
        </dict>
     </dict>
```

In the nodes part, I've added this

```
<key>Nodes</key>
    <array>
        <string>AppDelegate.h</string>
        <string>main/</string>
        <string>main/objc/</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: I'm facing same problem. Do you got any solution?

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19037462/xcode-templates-moving-appdelegate

Comment: I'm able to change the group of Appdelegate. I want to change the physical path also. What I did is put a fuller structure in the template directory. And given the root folders name in the Nodes section. Now the folder structure is creating and corresponding group structure also creating. App delegate come under the group Classes/Appdelegate but it is created in the Xcode projects directory itself.